# wamp server not working on win10

Tags: wamp, windows-10, wampserver

My WAMP server is not working whatever i do.

- I disabled IIS so it is not occupying port `80`.
  [image]
- Then checking it in `cmd` with command `netstat -ao` its not there
  [image]
- I have WAMPServer 64bit so i checked `wampapache64` and `wampmysqld64` in Task Manager

[image]

And found that `wampapache64` is not running. Tried to run it through `WAMP>Apache>Services>Start/Resume` and tried manually in Task Manager does not start it.

- WAMP icon still orange and not green.

[image]

Does anyone have any idea?

**Update**

In `cmd` i went to `cd C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin` then `httpd.exe -e debug` and it outputed me an error in `httpd.conf`

[image]

Checked that line and it was my fault :) when modified with `notepad` probably entered it... Geez...

So anyway after fixing that it started showing missing files 
[image]

Comment: Any errors in error log or server logs? If the icon is orange, it could mean it encountered an error while starting the server that could shed light on the problems.

Comment: Just a mmoment found something

Comment: it works... just restarted all services and thats it...

Comment: Do `left click on wampmanager icon->Apache->Version->2.4.9` and click on the `2.4.9` menu. It will rebuild the SYMLINKS and that extension will load